# How does ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION introduced in Android Q affect Geofence APIs?

Tags: android, android-location, android-geofence, android-10.0

In order to use the Geofence API the user [has to give](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#RequestGeofences) the app `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. This location is considered to be dangerous and can be revoked at any time; once this permission is revoked, the app can not request the geofence updates.

How does `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission fit in this picture? We know for sure that this permission is also [dangerous](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) and [can be revoked at any time](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/device-location). Does it mean that if we want to register some `IntentService` to be invoked every time the geofence change occurs, we also have to make sure the user has provided `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission? Or do we need to use this permission **only** if we attempt to get a current location in our own background Service/BroadcastReceiver?

The reason I'm asking this question is that the documentation seems to be a bit vague at this point: the documentation describing the [Q Developer Preview](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/device-location) mentions that geofencing is one of the use cases for the background location retrieval, while the [Geofencing API page](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing) does not mention `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` among its requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My *guess* the section "[Re-register geofences only when required](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#re-register-geofences-only-when-required)":

> Registered geofences are kept in the `com.google.process.location` process owned by the `com.google.android.gms` package.

will be that it is not really needed, as `com.google.process.location` should be the one getting the location data (so the one needing to request the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission).

That being said, following this logic `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission should neither be needed. The fact that it is needed may be because of two reasons (I don't know the real reason):

- that either when registering the geofence or when receiving a notification location is checked,
- or that this permission is checked by Google Play Services to forbid an app to circumvent the lack of location permission by using Play Services as a proxy process to obtain the information.

For me, the second assumption makes more sense, meaning that even when technically will not be needed by the app (the process getting the location is Play Service), it is required for privacy/security reasons.

Following this logic, Google should (will?) also enforce the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`, both to ensure user's privacy/security and to reduce battery consumption.

Comment: Yup, my thinking was exactly the same: on one hand the geofences-related work (which would require the permissions) happens in separate process, hence the background location permission would not be required; on the other hand the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission is required nevertheless.

Answer (score 8):

[Geofencing API Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing) is now updated and we need to define `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` to monitor Geofences if we target Android Q

From the doc:

> To use geofencing, your app must request ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. If your app targets Android 10 (API level 29) or higher, your app must also request ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION.

Answer (score 4):

On beta 4, adding a geofence when `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` is not granted, even when the app is fully in the foreground, fails with status code 13 ("error").

Answer (score 0):

You need Android 10 API Level 29+ to use ACCES_BACKGROUND_LOCATION